# Can't extract multiple diamonds from one chest Minecraft Pocket Edition

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

So on Minecraft Pocket Edition, I have 64 diamonds and when I open a chest, I hold down on the diamonds until the green bar fills up and when I let go it only puts one diamond and this happens with all my worlds so please tell me what to do.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Minecraft? What device are you playing on? Have you tried not letting go until the end?

Answer (score 0):

This happens to my brother...he has latest version. just switch your UI in the settings to classic when you want to transfer stacks of items to chests [image]